# After hosting application Images are not displayed,css is not applied

Tags: html, css, image, deployment

After i hosted my HTML5 application on Apache tomcat.My page is not showing any background image.
I have placed my project folder (MyExpert) inside root folder and inside MyExpert folder  there is an image folder and a css folder .I am giving background image as

> background-image:url(../images/myprofile_on.png)

in my css file but images are not coming on my pages except home page.Though application is working fine on localhost.I tried various thing but no fruitful result.

Comment: Can you share your full folder+file structure?

Comment: be sure website have read-access to the folder `/images`, a very common "error" when creating dirs on apacheservers remote. Bet you can see and 404 for the picture.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it will be a simple referencing or permissions issue here, try nivgating directly to the image in your browser and see if you can navigate to it manually so is this case given your description it would be:

http://www.yourdomain.com/MyExpert/images/myprofile_on.png

If that works then its a simple referencing issue from you css file, if it returns a forbidden access page you know its permissions, if it returns a file not found I would recommend checking the casing on your CSS url to ensure it matches the file path as if your box is linux then file paths are most likely case sensitive.